Tanstack Query with Expo and React Native useQuery().error returning always null
i'm building an Expo/React Native app, with app folder structure (instead of App.tsx main file), but I'm trying to implement Tanstack Query in my project, but I'm getting the error object returned always as null even if I explicitly throw the error in my queryFn property.
My app/(auth)/login.tsx

import { KeyboardAvoidingView, Text } from "react-native";

import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query"

export default function Login() {

  const query = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['test'],
    queryFn: async () => {
      if (true) {
        throw new Error('test')
      }
    },
  })

  if (query.error) {
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        <Text>{query.error.message}</Text>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  } else {
    console.log(query)
    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding">
        <Text>Success</Text>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    )
  }
}

app/(auth)/layout.tsx
import { Stack } from "expo-router";

export default function AuthLayout() {
  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen name="login" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
}

app/layout.tsx
import { router, Stack, useRootNavigationState } from "expo-router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import '@/lang/i18n';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'react-native-magnus';
import { onlineManager, focusManager, QueryCache, QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo"
import { AppState } from "react-native";
import type { AppStateStatus } from "react-native";

const query_client = new QueryClient({
  queryCache: new QueryCache(),
})

export default function RootLayout() {
  const navigation_state = useRootNavigationState()
  const navigator_ready = navigation_state?.key !== null

  useEffect(() => {
    if(navigator_ready) {
      router.replace('/(auth)/login')
    }
  }, [navigator_ready])

  useEffect(() => {
    onlineManager.setEventListener((setOnline) => {
      return NetInfo.addEventListener((state) => {
        setOnline(!!state.isConnected);
      })
    })
  }, [NetInfo, onlineManager])

  useEffect(() => {
    const subscriber = AppState.addEventListener('change', onFocusRefetch);

    return () => {
      subscriber.remove();
    }
  }, [])

  const onFocusRefetch = (status: AppStateStatus) => {
    focusManager.setFocused(status === 'active');
  }
  
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={query_client}>
      <ThemeProvider>
        <Stack>
          <Stack.Screen name="(auth)" options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          {/* <Stack.Screen name="(home)" options={{ headerShown: false }}/> */}
          {/* <Stack.Screen name="(checklist)" options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="(fleet)" options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="(admin)" options={{ headerShown: false }}/> */}
        </Stack>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
}


What I'm doing wrong to return the error always as null?
This is what returns if I console.log the query object after it executes the queryFn function:
{"data": undefined, "dataUpdatedAt": 0, "error": null, "errorUpdateCount": 5, "errorUpdatedAt": 1731019239744, "failureCount": 3, "failureReason": [Error: test], "fetchStatus": "fetching", "isError": false, "isFetched": true, "isFetchedAfterMount": false, "isFetching": true, "isInitialLoading": true, "isLoading": true, "isLoadingError": false, "isPaused": false, "isPending": true, "isPlaceholderData": false, "isRefetchError": false, "isRefetching": false, "isStale": true, "isSuccess": false, "promise": {"_h": 1, "_i": 2, "_j": [Error: experimental_prefetchInRender feature flag is not enabled], "_k": null, "reason": [Error: experimental_prefetchInRender feature flag is not enabled], "status": "rejected"}, "refetch": [Function bound refetch], "status": "pending"}

My Tanstack query version: 5.59.20
